# Names referencing other franchises in The Expanse final episode

Tags: the-expanse-2015, reference

[image]

I noticed a few familiar names in the squads on the Rocinante in the final series episode.

Notably: (as best as I can make out)

Alpha Squad - (other than Bobbi Draper & Alex Burton)

- G. Ackbar *- Star Wars*
- D. Idaho *- Dune*
- D. Bowman *- 2001*
- C. Shepard *?*
- A. Rogan *?*
- J. Nesmith
- E. Black *?*

Bravo Squad

- K. Garrity *?*
- H. Ochan *?*
- E. Riply *- Aliens*
- J. Vasquez *- Aliens*
- D. Hicks *- Aliens*
- W. Hudson *- Aliens*
- J. Cooper *?*
- W. Deckard *- Blade Runner*
- J. Anderton *?*
- J. O'Neil *- Stargate*

Charlie Squad

- E. Levine *?*
- J. Rico *-Starship Troopers*
- L. Starr *?*
- K. Thrace *- Battlestar Galactica*
- L. Banks *?*
- S. Connor *- Terminator*
- K. Flynn *-?*
- E. Stone *?*
- B. Heahy *?*
- W. Roger *?*

Some of the initials/last names may be off, it's low quality image and only on screen for a few seconds.

**Can we identify the ones I've missed (or need correction)?**

Comment: Here is a link to a similar question: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/116780/the-expanse-and-aliens-correllation   And here uis a link to an article in Forbes about it:  https://www.forbes.com/sites/paultassi/2022/01/16/amazons-the-expanse-finale-packed-30-easter-eggs-into-one-shot/?sh=646d6aa8184c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, let's start this:

#### ALPHA

- B. Draper - *The Expanse*
- G. Ackbar - *Star Wars*
- D. Quaid - *Total Recall*
- D. Bowman - *2001*
- C. Shepard - Commander Shepard *Mass Effect*
- A. Burton - *The Expanse*
- D. Idaho - *Dune*
- A. Rogan - *The Last Starfighter*
- J. Nesmith - Commander Taggart *Galaxy Quest*
- E. Buck -*Halo*

#### BRAVO

- K. Garrity - Kathleen Garrity, co-showrunner's Karate teacher<sup>1</sup>
- E. Ripley - *Aliens*
- D. Hicks - *Aliens*
- J. Cooper - *Interstellar* ("Coop")
- J. Anderton - *Minority Report*
- H. Ochiai - Hidy Ochai, co-showrunner's Sensei<sup>1</sup>
- J. Vasquez - *Aliens*
- W. Hudson - *Aliens*
- W. Deckard - *Blade Runner*
- J. O'Neil - *Stargate*

#### CHARLIE

- R. Levine- Rob Levine, co-showrunners black belt<sup>1</sup>
- L. Starr - *Lucky Starr and ...*
- L. Banks - Louise Banks *Arrival*
- K. Flynn - *Tron*
- R. Neary - *Close Encounters of the Third Kind*
- J. Rico - *Starship Troopers*
- K. Thrace - *Battlestar Galactica*
- S. Connor - *Terminator*
- R. Stone - Ryan Stone *Gravity*
- W. Riker - *Star Trek*

<sup>[Twitter Reference - 1](https://twitter.com/narenshankar/status/1482162874130657281?t=ktSjDGFmEaSecBc7ssSO6w&s=19)</sup>

[image]